# Python package thinks I have older version of dependency than I do

Tags: python, installation, version, h2o, colorama

I'm trying to use the h2o package. I'm running macOS Mojave with Anaconda installed.

I've done a `pip install h2o` and it was successful. It installed at location `/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

I try to import it and get this error message: "H2O requires colorama module of version 0.3.8 or newer. You have version 0.3.7."

But when I do `pip show colorama` it says I have version 0.4.1, so the error message doesn't make sense. It's installed at the same location as h2o at  `/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Anaconda, I would recommend creating a new conda environment and then conda installing all the packages you need (for H2O you would use `conda install -c h2oai h2o=3.22.1.2` ). This will help prevent package conflicts or having trouble pointing to the correct version.

you should also run `conda list` to see whether you have another version of colorma installed. Alternatively, you could do a `pip uninstall colorama` and see whether H2O still picks up a 0.3.7 version - at the very least it will help reveal whether you have multiple versions.

Comment: conda list picks up two versions of colorama...0.3.9  and 0.4.1. No 0.3.7, funnily enough. So I uninstalled and reinstalled colorama, and now `import h2o` works. Strange.